# Bootstrap Carousel: Slide Thumbnail with Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use image thumbnail instead of orderd list for carousel indicators. I followed some instructions here and created this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rowin_aria/vLor5u5L/1/)

It works fine, but as you can see the thumbnails has a scroll bar to fit them all. How can I slide/move thumbnails as the carousel slides?

Here is the CSS that creates the thumbnail:

```
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: static;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: auto;
}

#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li.active img {
  opacity: 1;
}

#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li:hover img {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

#carousel-custom .carousel-outer {
  position: relative;
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
 interval: 10000
 })
    
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
     //alert("slid");
 });
    
    
});
```

```css
.carousel-control {
  padding-top:10%;
  width:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Bootstrap Thumbnail Slider</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> 
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This creates the thumbnail which is awesome but I still want the carousel to show bigger images at the top while you go through the slides. Just like my example but make the thumbnails as you created. Thank you for your help. Any suggestions appreciated